# Can sync.WaitGroup safely be reused?

Tags: go

Can `sync.WaitGroup` be reused after `Wait()` is called?

```
func worker(who string, in <-chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := range in {
        fmt.Println(who, i)
        wg.Done()
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    AIn := make(chan int, 1)
    BIn := make(chan int, 1)

    go worker("a:", AIn, &wg)
    go worker("b:", BIn, &wg)

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        wg.Add(2)
        AIn <- i
        BIn <- i
        wg.Wait()
        fmt.Println("main:", i)
    }
}
```

This [play.golang.org/p/QLsvA-b4Ae](http://play.golang.org/p/QLsvA-b4Ae) runs as expected, but is it guaranteed to be safe? The documentation doesn't say so, but maybe I'm just being paranoid.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. In fact, it is even safer than that. You can `Wait` from multiple goroutines concurrently, and interchange `Add` and `Done` calls as appropriate for your use case. As long as the `Add` happens before the `Wait`, you should be safe.

Just out of curiosity, right now the `WaitGroup` is implemented with a mutex, two int32s counters, and a semaphore:

```
type WaitGroup struct {
        m       Mutex
        counter int32
        waiters int32
        sema    *uint32
}
```

This is also an interesting test:

```
var wg1, wg2 sync.WaitGroup
wg1.Add(1)
wg1.Done()
wg1.Wait()
fmt.Println(wg1 == wg2) // Prints true
```

Finally, if you do find any issues with that kind of use, please report as it would be a bug.