# Do we need to create new waitgroups after it's done waiting?

Tags: go, concurrency

I am facing a bit of a concurrency issue.
I am writing a concurrent application for the first time.

### What I am trying to achieve

Dependent functions ( using goroutines ) i.e. `func2` is dependent on the result of `func1`

### Problem

If I reuse the waitgroup after it's done **waiting** I get an error as

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Here's my code ( [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MHUFUps2p3T) ) :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    ch := make(chan int)
    for a := 0; a < 3; a++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func1(int(3-a), ch, &wg)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()
    //wg2 := sync.WaitGroup{} //<-- If I uncomment this and the corresponding wg2 code, then the snippet runs fine
    ch2 := make(chan string)
    for val := range ch {
        fmt.Println(val)
        wg.Add(1)
        //wg2.Add(1)
        go func2(val, ch2, &wg)
        //go func2(val, ch2, &wg2)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        //wg2.Wait()
        close(ch2)
    }()
    for val := range ch2 {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}

func func1(seconds int, ch chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(seconds) * time.Second)
    ch <- seconds
}

func func2(seconds int, ch chan<- string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ch <- "hello"
}
```

So, you can see, if I create a new `WaitGroup` it works fine else deadlock arises.

Thanks
Temporarya
( A golang noobie )

Answer (score 2):

WaitGroups [can be safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523425/can-sync-waitgroup-safely-be-reused) reused but it's not clear why you're using a third-party package for this? Especially if you're just learning concurrency, I would strongly recommend you to stick to the standard library - `sync.WaitGroup` is what you need.

FWIW, if I modify your code to use `sync.WaitGroup`, it doesn't deadlock and runs to completion - see [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cA4cw_T-xyD)

[This Go blog post](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) explains how to do pipelining safely with channels, and in some more advanced cases wait groups (you don't always need them)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer.
I am using third party package, to limit the no of goroutines.

Comment: This code( which I posted )  is working fine, but it won't work if I don't create a new `swg2`. That's what the whole question is about.

Comment: @temporarya: reusing it in this case seems like a bad idea because at the point where swg2 is created the existing wait group is not even done yet - func1 only does wg.Done after the channel has been read from. Don't forget that writing to an unbuffered channel blocks until it has been read from

Comment: Thanks Eli, can you please have a look at the erroneous code ( I have updated the play link and the question's code ). Also, so the best course of action to use the data from `func1` and send it to `func2` would be to create a new `WaitGroup`. I am currently having a look at the blogpost link you mentioned above. Thanks again.

Comment: Pipelines looks like the answer to my problem ( instead of the workaround I am currently struggling with ), also I read about some `EventBus` thing, is it needed ( I am talking for bigger projects ) ? Like[this](https://github.com/asaskevich/EventBus)

Comment: @temporarya: I would say you don't even need wait groups here just to communicate data between two goroutines - channels are fine for that, and they create a synchronization point. Use the methods shown in the blog post I linked to, instead. Don't worry about more advanced use cases before you've mastered the simple ones

Comment: I don't need WaitGroup ? So, I am supposing that You're telling me to make a new channel in func1 and call func2 from that itself communicating through that channel, is it so ? But I don't think that's what you meant , by not using wait groups.

Comment: @temporarya: Very long comment discussions are discouraged as they're hard to follow and the question/answer keep changing on the fly. I think you should create a new question explaining what you're trying to accomplish, with your best attempt at doing that. I believe your original question here has already been answered